# Merging many individual .tex files

Tags: join

I have about 200 short .tex files, all different names. I would like to merge all those files into one large .tex file, specifically, each file a seperate page. How would I do this, without individually inputting them one by one into a main.tex?

Comment: Are they each complete tex documents, with their own `\documentclass`?  Is there a consistent naming scheme, or do they have various names?  Are they all located in one (or a few) directories, or are they spread out through many?  Your best bet might end up being using some other programming language to write the onelarge.tex file.

Comment: Not an answer right now because I'm going to bed, but I'd do it with an external program. I did something similar last year with a Python script that skipped the preamble of a LaTeX file to process the main body. Would something inspired from that be an acceptable solution? If yes, I'll try to come up with the script as soon as possible.

Comment: I was recently messing with Multi-file project (See this [link to a blog on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects)). The files you are going to insert must be prepared and correctly added to the main file. If you do that, you can have the whole project in one PDF as well as compile individual files into separate PDFs, e.g. for test. To prepare files I would probably use Python with a regular expression. Overleaf also explains an alternative approach.

Comment: Look for the standalone package? (it doesn't satisfy the "input one by one" condition though)

Comment: If you have simple text files that can exported to markdown without messing or losing contents,  an  easy solution could be (1) create a bookdown  or quatro project in R studio  project, once it worked,  (2) make a bulk export of .tex to .md files with pandoc,  (3) put the files the .md files in the directory project  and finally (4) compile the project to PDF. This will merge all the markdown files and export to PDF via LaTeX (you can retain the latex single version using `keep_tex: yes`) If every document start with a chapter, moreover each will be by default in a new odd page.